# Apache Spark -- Parsing the data and convert columns into rows

Tags: apache-spark

I need to convert the columns into rows .Please help me in the below requirement in spark scala code.input file is | delimiter and one of the column having comma delimiter value.based on the comma delimiter i need to convert them into rows

my input records:

c11|c12|a,b|c14

c21|c22|a,c,d|c24

expected output :

a,c11,c12,c14

b,c11,c12,c14

a,c21,c22,c24

c,c21,c22,c24

d,c21,c22,c24

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

First read the dataframe as csv with | as a separator:

This provides a dataframe with the base columns you need except the third which would be a string. Lets say you renamed this column to be called _c2 (the default name for the third column). Now you can split the string to get an array
We also remove the previous column as we don't need it anymore.
Lastly we use explode to turn the array to rows and drop the unused column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df1 = spark.read.csv("pathToFile", sep="|")
df2 = df1.withColumn("splitted", split(df1["_c2"],",")).drop("_c2")
df3 = df2.withColumn("exploded", explode(df2["splitted"])).drop("splitted")
```

or in scala (free form)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
val df1 = spark.read.csv("pathToFile", sep="|")
val df2 = df1.withColumn("splitted", split(df1("_c2"),",")).drop("_c2")
val df3 = df2.withColumn("exploded", explode(df2("splitted"))).drop("splitted")
```